# Unable to upload .avi files using php form

Tags: php, html, file-upload

have tried uploading .avi video formats but the page just refreshes and the file is not uploaded all other types type images and everything is getting uploaded im posting my code here look for file uploding sections with cwf and ve

```
<?php
 $n=5;
     $exp_no="";
    $shot_no="";
    $file_name1="";
    $file_name2="";
    $remarks="";
    $cwf="";
    $vedio="";
        $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","project");
        if(!$conn){
             die("connection failed");
            echo "<br/>";
        }
        $query="select stage from experimentdetails where NO='{$exp_no}'"; 
        $res=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){
            $r=mysqli_fetch_row($res);
                    $n=$r[0];
        }

    session_start();
    $exp_no=$_SESSION["expno_add"];
    $s=mysqli_query($conn,"select ShotNo from shotdetails where ExpNo='{$exp_no}'");
    $res=mysqli_fetch_row($s);
    $shot_no=$res[0];
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $remarks=$_POST["remarks"];
        $cap=array(8);
        $off=array(8);
        $cv=array(8);
        $cptp=array(8);
        $pul=array(8);
        $del=array(8);
        $vel=array(8);
        for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)
        {
            if($i<$n)
            {
                $j=$i+1;
                     $cap[$i]=$_POST["cv{$j}"];
                    $off[$i]=$_POST["off{$j}"];
                    $cv[$i]=$_POST["cc{$j}"];
                    $cptp[$i]=$_POST["cpt{$j}"];
                    $pul[$i]=$_POST["pw{$j}"];
                    $del[$i]=$_POST["del{$j}"];
                    $vel[$i]= $_POST["vel{$j}"];

            }
            else{
                    $cap[$i]=0;
                    $off[$i]=0;
                    $cv[$i]=0;
                    $cptp[$i]=0;
                    $pul[$i]=0;
                    $del[$i]=0;
                    $vel[$i]=0;
            }
        }
         if($_FILES['cwf']['name']!="")
        {
         $fname=$_FILES["cwf"];
           $uploaddir = 'cwf/'; 
          if (is_uploaded_file($fname['tmp_name'])) 
          { 
              $filname = basename($fname['name']); 
              $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($fname['name']); 
             if (move_uploaded_file ($fname['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
                  $r = "File " . $filname . " was successfully uploaded and stored.<br>"; 
              else 
               $r = "Could not move ".$fname['tmp_name']." to ".$uploadfile."<br>"; 
          } 
           else 
               $r = "File ".$fname['name']." failed to upload."; 
           $file_name1='cwf/'.$file_name1;
        }
        if($_FILES['ve']['name']!="")
        {
         $fname=$_FILES["ve"];
           $uploaddir = 'upload/'; 
          if (is_uploaded_file($fname['tmp_name'])) 
          { 
              $filname = basename($fname['name']); 
              $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($fname['name']); 
             if (move_uploaded_file ($fname['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
                  $r = "File " . $filname . " was successfully uploaded and stored.<br>"; 
              else 
               $r = "Could not move ".$fname['tmp_name']." to ".$uploadfile."<br>"; 
          } 
           else 
               $r = "File ".$fname['name']." failed to upload."; 
            $file_name2='upload/'.$file_name2;
        }
        $query="insert into shotdetails values($shot_no,$cap[0],$cap[1],$cap[2],$cap[3],$cap[4],$cap[5],$cap[6],$cap[7],$off[0],$off[1],$off[2],$off[3],$off[4],$off[5],$off[6],$off[7],$cptp[0],$cptp[1],$cptp[2],$cptp[3],$cptp[4],$cptp[5],$cptp[6],$cptp[7],$pul[0],$pul[1],$pul[2],$pul[3],$pul[4],$pul[5],$pul[6],$pul[7],$del[0],$del[1],$del[2],$del[3],$del[4],$del[5],$del[6],$del[7],$vel[0],$vel[1],$vel[2],$vel[3],$vel[4],$vel[5],$vel[6],$vel[7],$file_name1,$file_name2,$remarks,$exp_no,$cv[0],$cv[1],$cv[2],$cv[3],$cv[4],$cv[5],$cv[6],$cv[7])";
       mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ADD Shot</title>
         <style>
    select {
        padding:3px;
        margin: 0;
        -webkit-border-radius:4px;
        -moz-border-radius:4px;
        border-radius:4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
        background: #f8f8f8;
        color:#888;
        border:none;
        outline:none;
        display: inline-block;
        -webkit-appearance:none;
        -moz-appearance:none;
        appearance:none;
        cursor:pointer;
        }
        /* Targetting Webkit browsers only. FF will show the dropdown arrow with so much padding. */
        @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
        select {padding-right:18px}
        }
        label {position:relative}
        label:after {
        content:'<>';
        font:11px "Consolas", monospace;
        color:#aaa;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
        transform:rotate(90deg);
        right:8px; top:2px;
        padding:0 0 2px;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
        position:absolute;
        pointer-events:none;
        }
        label:before {
        content:'';
        right:6px; top:0px;
        width:20px; height:20px;
        background:#f8f8f8;
        position:absolute;
        pointer-events:none;
        display:block;
        }
        .c ul li {
            margin-top: 11px;
        margin-right: 6px;
        padding: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: open-sans, Araial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;

       }
       .c li a {

        margin-left: 10px;
    color:black;
        padding-right: 20px;

    text-decoration: none;
       }
       .c{
        margin-left: 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.20);
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.20);
    border-radius:5px;
        width:98%;
        margin-top: 10px;
       }
       #nav {
            height: 40px;
            border-radius:3px;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
            border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="c">
        <ul  id="nav">
                <li style="border-right:1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.65);">
            <a href="add_exp.php">Add Experiment</a> 
        </li>
        <li  style="border-right:1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.65);">
            <a href="mod_exp.php">Modify Experiment</a>
        </li>
        <li style="border-right:1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.65);">
            <a href="del_exp.php">Delete Experiment</a> 
        </li>
        <li style="border-right:1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.65);">
            <a href="new_shot.php">Create New Shot</a>
        </li>
        <li style="border-right:1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.65);">
            <a href="del_shot.php">Delete Shot</a>
        </li>
        <li style="border-right:1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.65);">
            <a href="add_comp.php">Add Component</a>
        </li>
                <li style="border-right:1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.65);">
            <a href="mod_comp.php">Modify Component</a>
        </li>
                <li style="border-right:1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.65);">
            <a href="del_comp.php">Delete Component</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
        <center style="margin-top:5%">
        <form action="add_shot1.php" method="POST" name="add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4" class="cap">
               <tr>
                   <th>Stage No.</th>
                   <th>Charging Voltage(kV)</th>
                   <th>Offset(mm)</th>
                   <th>Coil Current(kA)</th>
                   <th>Current Pulse Time period(ms)</th>
                   <th>Pulse Width(ms)</th>
                   <th>Delay(ms)</th>
                   <th>Velocity</th>
               </tr>
           <?php

               for ($x = 1; $x <= $n; $x++) {
                       echo "<tr>";
                       echo "<td align='center'>" . $x . "</td>";
                       echo "<td  align='center' ><input type='number' class='text' name='cv{$x}' value='' style=' height:30px;'/></td>";
                       echo "<td align='center'><input type='number' class='text' name='off{$x}' value=''style=' height:30px;'/></td>";
                       echo "<td align='center' ><input type='number' class='text' name='cc{$x}' value=''style=' height:30px;'/></td>";
                       echo "<td align='center' ><input type='number' class='text' name='cpt{$x}' value=''style=' height:30px;'/></td>";
                       echo "<td align='center' ><input type='number' class='text' name='pw{$x}' value=''style=' height:30px;'/></td>";
                       echo "<td align='center' ><input type='number' class='text' name='del{$x}' value=''style=' height:30px;'/></td>";
                       echo "<td align='center' ><input type='number' class='text' name='vel{$x}' value=''style=' height:30px;'/></td>";
                       echo"</tr>";
               } 
           ?>
                   <tr>
                        <td colspan='4'> Current wave form file: &nbsp;&nbsp <input type='file' name='cwf' value='' class='text'/> </td>
                   </tr>

               <tr >
                   <td colspan='4' >Video File: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='file' name='ve' value='' class='text'/></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Remarks</td>
                   <td><textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="remarks" value=""></textarea></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
              <td colspan=4 align='center'><input type="submit"  name="submit" value="submit"  /></td>
               </tr>
           </table>
         </form>
        </center>
       </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your video files are probably too big. Have you checked the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` values in php.ini?

Comment: what's the file size? Any error that you see?

Comment: checked all of them i am using wamp server.no error at all

Comment: post your complete code

Comment: at the start of your file, set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` what is in your `$r` after upload?

Comment: $r is echoed later for errors

Comment: if any one can give me a working php script for uploading avi files i would be grateful